# Astro: browser or server side?

Tags: reactjs, window, server-side-rendering, astrojs

How to detect if astro rendering happens in browser or on the server side?

Found no info in official reference and troubleshooting guide.

The only 'advice' I found is to use 'client:only'.

**UPDATE** Solution found

```js
    export const isCLientSide = typeof window !== 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the `window` object using `globalThis`. If `window` is present, you are on the client.

```
if (globalThis.window) {
    console.log('Hello client-side!')
}

if (!globalThis.window) {
    console.log('Hello server-side!')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the code is running on the server by using `import.meta.env.SSR` provided by [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables).

```js
if (import.meta.env.SSR) {
  // The app is running on the server.
} else {
  // Running in the browser.
}
```

For example for a code that uses the `window` object and should only run on the client:

```js
function clientCode() {
  if (import.meta.env.SSR) return;

  // Run client code.
  window.alert('...');
}
```